# ATX PSU With only +5VSB output

Tags: atx

I am searching some thread about but i don't find it.

3 days ago. My ATX power supply has burn by overheat. Thermaltake TR2 600W.

it has a OTP and even with that it hasn't turned off. Blown by overheat.
But aside that. What i am intrigued is, WHY the heck only the +5VSB is giving me output. The other +5V and 12V, -12V, and 3.3V has fall out.

Maybe the secondary side has burned. or the +5VSB is independent from the primary side.

Maybe transistor. Transformer.What is more common?

Anyone know about it?

I can't fide any circuit similar what i have. and isn't available this schematic.

Thanks.

---

Thanks for people that has actually tried to help. but i don't understand why my question has been negative.

Some people, i guess, have the same question and didn't have the courage of asking the question or don't know how to ask the question. I had researched much before asking this. This atx by me has been like dead. Because it isn't trusted to be used on PC. But i am using an atx that i recovered by changing the capacitor before 500w.

but if i recover this thermaltake, it can be used as a power supply bench.
Tried Reverse engineer it, but it's a complex circuit. so only could do main component.

the dead atx has not any signal of burned component, so i will verify any point on board. Transistor, Transformer. Voltage on each path.

So just assumed that i want the answer resolved. Or it can't be useful to anyone. or if it is Unclear, Just ask again what i meant by that.

Again, thanks for the guide.

Comment: You may be aware already, but just in case I'll mention that if you are powering the supply up on the bench and not connected to the PC then you need to enable the power supply with a jumper as mentioned on a number of sites including this one : http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-power-up-an-ATX-Power-Supply-without-a-PC/

Comment: Some years after your post, I've readed it and upvoted your post, now you're just -1. Saddly, people here are like that. There was been some improvement about how novice questions are treated, but don't wait so much help. Specially if your name and surname are not of plain anglo-saxon origin. Yours "D'Avila" is Spanish, isn't it? But they could have treated you worst, if your user name was Arabic, Eastern, or from India.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern ATX12V power supplies for personal computers are specifically designed to have the standby voltage SEPARATELY from main power conversion path. The +5VSB is a separate small AC-DC converter that is used to supply wake-up and start-up circuitry within mainboard PC, and turn the main power keeping right sequencing. For more details, consult with [**official ATX12V design guide**](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/atx12v_psdg_2_2_public_br2.pdf), and many [**other useful collections**](http://educypedia.karadimov.info/computer/pchardwaresupply.htm) of actual schematics and other data.

If your PSU outputs only +5VSB and nothing else works, it means that either the PS_ON# controller IC (inside PSU) has died, or the main power path has died.

Answer (score 1):

> WHY the heck only the +5VSB is giving me output.

It is likely that the 5VSB is largely seperate from the rest of the power supply (probablly sharing the rectifier but not much more) for a couple or reasons.

1. The main converter (especially in older designs) is likely to be inefficient at low power. So having it running in standby mode would be wasteful.
2. Switching transistors have losses, so the designer will want to minimise the number of them in the main power path. Turning off the main converter completely only involves turning off existing switching transistor in the converter. Keeping the main converter running while turning off it's output would require extra switching transistors.